# How to retain the current tab when updating a page?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a horizontal tab system set up like so:

```
<a id="default" class="link" href="#">Tab 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Tab 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#">Tab 3</a>
```

Which works using basic HTML and CSS.

I also have a table for each that can handle sorting through PHP that causes a page redirect that puts the new sorting type in the URL.

However, if I am in, let's say, the third tab, and click the change the sorting type, the page changes and the sorting type is changed by now it goes back to tab 1. How can I have it retain what tab it was in previously?

Comment: You could use a url parameter to indicate which tab is active

Comment: or you could use a cookie, depending what you prefer.

Comment: or user server-side code to set the default tab when the page loads based on the previous url.

Comment: How does the page "know" what tab it's on in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow on your table that uses server-side sorting, you are passing the server information.  It may be with a form

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/tabs.php?sortTab2=a" />
```

Or links

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/tabs.php?sortTab2=a">Sort</a>
```

Either way, if you add a parameter to your querystring called `tab`, you can use php to print `id="default"` in your current tab.

```
<?php
$activeTab = isset($_REQUEST['tab']) ? $_REQUEST['tab'] : 1;
?>

<a <?php if($activetab == 1) echo 'id="default" '; ?>class="link" href="#">Tab 1</a>
<a <?php if($activetab == 2) echo 'id="default" '; ?>class="link" href="#">Tab 2</a>
<a <?php if($activetab == 3) echo 'id="default" '; ?>class="link" href="#">Tab 3</a>
```

Then, inside each tab, make sure you specify the `tab` query parameter however you're calling your php sort.

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/tabs.php?sortTab2=a&tab=2" />
<a href="http://www.example.com/tabs.php?sortTab2=a&tab=2">Sort</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, assign each tab an ID, then use .show() and .hide() . Benefits include no postback and lightning fast tab switching if you've got data in there.